# Mass invoices duplicate Odoo8

Tags: python, xml-rpc, odoo-8

Is there anyway to duplicate, or create, a bunch of invoices with xml-rpc?

I try with the copy method of the Odoo ORMApi

```
invoices = call('account.invoice','search_read', [('type','ilike',"out_invoice")])

for invoice in invoices:
inv = invoice.copy()
```

How can I insert the new invoice int the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try erppeek, it's a python library that makes this much easier

```
client = erppeek.Client(SERVER, DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
invoices=client.search('account.invoice',[('type','ilike',"out_invoice")])
for i in range(len(invoices)):
    client.copy('account.invoice',invoices[i-1])
```